# How to sort list of lists with alternate alphabetical value maintaining the association with adjacent numeric values

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a python list of lists like this

```
[['CCND1', '67', 'FAS', '99', 'IRAK3', '92', 'ALG14', '86', 'ADRBK1', '10'], ['PTRX', '95', 'CCNA', '33']]
```

Each alphabetical value is associated with the numeric value , i.e `IRAK3` and `92` are associated (`92`, should appear after `IRAK3`) and `PTRX` and `95` are associated (`95` should appear after `PTRX` ). Now , I want to alphabetically sort this list of lists so that the sorted list looks like this:

```
[['ADRBK1', '10', 'ALG14', '86', 'CCND1', '67', 'FAS', '99', 'IRAK3', '92' ], ['CCNA', '33', 'PTRX', '95' ]]
```

Note that in the sorted list, the alphabetical values are sorted but again, note that `92`, appear after `IRAK3` AND `95` appear after `PTRX` i.e the association is maintained.

How could I do that ?

Comment: Why did you put associated values in separate list elements, instead of combining them into a tuple or dict?

Comment: Which specific part of that are you having trouble with? I'd suggest splitting into pairs `("ADRBK1", "10")` and sorting those, then flattening it again.

Comment: Lists should generally be homogeneous. Use tuples and dictionaries for heterogeneous collections of related data.

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO isn't a code-writing service

Comment: This question is clear. Don't close it as unclear. (Witness the three to-the-point answers.) If you don't like the zero effort, then downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Lists should generally be homogeneous. Use tuples and dictionaries for heterogeneous collections of related data." [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59624083/how-to-sort-list-of-lists-with-alternate-alphabetical-value-maintaining-the-asso#comment105410681_59624083)

One approach would be you arrange them as tuples and then sorting them would also be easier.

```
mylist = [['CCND1', '67', 'FAS', '99', 'IRAK3', '92', 'ALG14', '86', 'ADRBK1', '10'], ['PTRX', '95', 'CCNA', '33']]

list_of_tuples = []
for l in mylist:
    if len(l) % 2 is not 0:
        raise ValueError()
    list_of_tuples.append([(l[i], l[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(l), 2)])

for l in list_of_tuples:
    l.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[0])

print(list_of_tuples)

# [[('ADRBK1', '10'), ('ALG14', '86'), ('CCND1', '67'), ('FAS', '99'), ('IRAK3', '92')], [('CCNA', '33'), ('PTRX', '95')]]
```

Comment: This only "works" because your give it input that is already sorted!

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import chain

data = [['CCND1', '67', 'FAS', '99', 'IRAK3', '92', 'ALG14', '86', 'ADRBK1', '10'], ['PTRX', '95', 'CCNA', '33']]
#pair elements --> [('CCND1', '67'), ('FAS', '99')....
data = [zip(i[::2], i[1::2]) for i in data]
#sort and flatten 
data = [list(chain.from_iterable(sorted(i, key=lambda x: x[0]))) for i in data]
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
>>> list_ = [['CCND1', '67', 'FAS', '99', 'IRAK3', '92', 'ALG14', '86', 'ADRBK1', '10'], ['PTRX', '95', 'CCNA', '33']]

>>> paired_list = (zip(*[iter(l)]*2) for l in list_)

>>> sorted_list = [list(sum(sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[0]),())) for l in paired_list]

>>> sorted_list

[['ADRBK1', '10', 'ALG14', '86', 'CCND1', '67', 'FAS', '99', 'IRAK3', '92'],
 ['CCNA', '33', 'PTRX', '95']]
```

References:

1. [`zip(*[iter(iterable)]*n)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2233204/5431791)
2. [`sorted`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/sorted.html)
3. I have used [`sum` to concatenate the list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42059707/5431791). However, if you are prepared to use other modules, it is always better to use [`itertools.chain.from_iterables`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable).